# Battle ship games that need to change its grid from X - D

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have a program using bash script

The purpose is to display output from test file into a grid style.

In my output.txt which is stored until $l is a1,a2,a3,a4,c1,c2

I have a function below which will display the following

mark_seat()
{

```
# Called by display_seats
if [ $(echo "$1" | grep -c "$2$3") -gt 0 ]
then    

    echo -en '\E[1;35mX\E[0m'
      set_colwidth "" 5

else

        set_colwidth "" 6 
fi
```

}

If unable to detect similar data in my $l, it will give a space as shown below.

My question is possible to set c1,c2 as destroyer ship thus when it display the output, it will show "D" rather than "X".

http://www.flickr.com/photos/70250115@N02/6381735021/

Comment: How will you know it's a destroyer from your original data? Bash can do if/else blocks so you will be able to do it with an extra clause like your original output.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with substring manipulation

assuming the positions are stored such that a string represents a row

```
A_ROW="____X_____"
echo ${A_ROW:0:4}D${A_ROW:5:4}
____D_____
```

however, there is also a trick to getting a character's position in a row

```
ASTRING="abcdefg"
POS_d=${ASTRING%d*}
echo position of d is ${#POS_d}
#note that POS_d is actually the string abc and ${#POS_d} is the length of abc
#since values start at 0, this is the position of d
#if you have multiple occurrences you can do this multiple times
```